# Update field automatically when adding a new entity

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, expression

I am trying to automatically update the content of several fields, when the first one is completed.
If the value in the first field is not found, then nothing. But if the value is found, then the field 2, 3, 4, etc. are updated with their respective content.

Ex: If The first feature is

- Field 1: "Test1"
- Field 2: "CODE1"
- Field 3: "CODE2"

Then, when I add another feature, if the content of the Field 1 is "Test1", the Field 2 will be completed with "CODE1" and the field 3 with "CODE2"

I have checked this page :
[Filling fields instantly and automatically when creating new entity in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321994/filling-fields-instantly-and-automatically-when-creating-new-entity-in-qgis)
The solution use python, and I'm not sure that this is my solution.
Other pages are mostly dedicated to ArcGIS.

I have tried several expressions in the Default value on update (FIELD1 = the entry, used to search correspondences, FIELD2 is one of the fields I want to update)

```
with_variable('V', get_feature('LAYER', 'FIELD1', "FIELD1"),
CASE
    WHEN @V IS NOT NULL AND @V <> ''
    THEN attribute(@V, 'FIELD2')
END
)
```

--

```
CASE
WHEN attribute(get_feature('LAYER', 'FIELD1', "FIELD1"), 'FIELD2') IS NOT NULL
THEN attribute(get_feature('LAYER', 'FIELD1', "FIELD1"), 'FIELD2')
END
```

--

```
attribute(get_feature('LAYER', 'FIELD1', "FIELD1"), 'FIELD2')
```

I add a first feature and complete attributes
[image: First entry]

Second, I would like to get the same attributes, when I use the same content in the first field.
[image: Result]

Right now, any of these expressions will automatically remove the content of the fields instead of completing it.
When I add a feature whose FIELD1 has no equivalent in the layer, then when I complete FIELD2 and FIELD3, the FIELD2 will be emptied, and vice versa.

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you're wanting even if its drawing/typing it manually. Struggling to get a grasp of what you're expecting the output to be.

Comment: I edited my first post with screenshots. I hope it can help show what I'm searching to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue by changing the expression :

```
    CASE WHEN "FIELD2" is NULL THEN
with_variable('existing_feature', get_feature('LAYER', 'FIELD1', "FIELD1"),
    CASE
        WHEN @existing_feature IS NOT NULL
        THEN attribute(@existing_feature, 'FIELD2')
        ELSE "FIELD2"
    END
)
ELSE
    "FIELD2"
END
```

This way, when I write an existing value in "FIELD1", the (first) corresponding value will be searched to auto-complete FIELD2.
I added a case if FIELD1 is NULL, so I can still change the value if I have to.

I put this expression in the default value of the fields I want to auto-complete.

There is no need to pre-configure another layer or relations.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing this problem could be effectively accomplished through the implementation of a Lookup table. The proposed methodology involves the establishment of a dual-layer structure. The first layer is exclusively designated for the retention of text inputs and pre-configured settings for automated code outputs. In contrast, the second layer serves as the repository for the authentic data. To streamline the process, we intend to pre-fill the Lookup table with anticipated inputs and corresponding outputs. By creating a linkage between the two tables and applying specific expressions to each field, we can enhance the overall functionality. This approach will be further augmented by incorporating user-friendly value mapping for added convenience.

**Step 1; Create the Lookup table layer and populate it with the input and output codes**

[image: Lookup table]

**Step 2; Create the layer you will manually input values into to receive the automated code outputs**

[image: Main Layer]

**Step 3; Create a join within your Main Layer,"join" layer**

[image: Creating Join]

**Step 4; Goto the attribute form in the Main Layer and add a default value and tick "Apply default value on update"**

*In my example I'm using;*

- *"attribute(get_feature('Join', 'field1', "Result"), 'field2')" for Code1*
- *"attribute(get_feature('Join', 'field1', "Result"), 'field3')" for Code2*
- *"attribute(get_feature('Join', 'field1', "Result"), 'field4')" for Code3*

**Image of Step 4**

[image: Image of expression form]

**Step 5; Create a value map to stream line data entry within the Main layer**

[image: Adding Value Map]

**Step 6; Create a new entry; examples**

[image: New entry1]

[image: Value map]

[image: New entry2]

[image: New entry3]

[image: New entry4]

[image: New entry5]

**Final Output**

[image: Final Output]

Comment: If I understand well, the solution you proposed requires to save in another table the association between "Result" and "Code1", "Code2", "Code3", etc. 
In my situation, I don't know which code will be associated to the "Result".
For "Test1", it might be "A1", A2, "A3", or anything else.